# Linq to XML data structure

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my XML:

```
<home>
  <contents>
    <row>
        <content>
            <idContent>1</idContent>
            <title>title1</title>
        </content>
        <content>
            <idContent>2</idContent>
            <title>title2</title>
        </content>
    </row>
    <row>
        <content>
            <idContent>3</idContent>
            <title>title3</title>
        </content>
        <content>
            <idContent>4</idContent>
            <title>title4</title>
        </content>
    </row>
</contents>
```

I want to store this information in a list of objects

List myList = ...

Where a Content could be:

```
int idContent;
string title;
int row_number;
```

Each Content object has to store the row where it is located in the XML.

What's the best way for doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by row_number?  The text-file linenumber? XLinq doesn't capture that, and in XML it's mostly meaningless. Setting a sequence-number on the other hand is easy.

Comment: Right. First two contents will store row=1, next two row=2, ... If we ignore this, what's the easiest xlinq for getting my xml? thx

Comment: Right, I missed that <row> tag.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming `row_number` is simply a sequence relating to the order it appears in the XML, then you can do something like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var contents = doc.Descendants("row")
    .Select((e, index) => new {Row = e, RowIndex = index})
    .SelectMany(x => x.Row.Elements("content").Select(e => new {Content = e, x.RowIndex}))
    .Select(x => new Content
    {
        IdContent = (int)x.Content.Element("idContent"),
        Title = (string)x.Content.Element("title"),
        RowNumber = x.RowIndex + 1
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could think of - although it is not using Linq to XML - is to feed your XML document into one of those various XML Schema generators like http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html and pipe this generated Schema right into xsd.exe (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx). The generated code can be used to read (and write) the XML document such as the one you provided and you can of course apply Linq to Objects on this collection.

However, since you mentioned the row_number field which does not yet appear in your example XML, you would have to add this to the XML or manually edit the XML Schema afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for similar scenarios:

```
public static Object CreateObject(string XMLString, Object YourClassObject)
{
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer oXmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(YourClassObject.GetType());
     //The StringReader will be the stream holder for the existing XML file 
     YourClassObject = oXmlSerializer.Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(XMLString));
     //initially deserialized, the data is represented by an object without a defined type 
     return YourClassObject;
}
```

With this method you can create a class object from a XML String. I haven't tested it on your scenario, but you can use it on object of following `home` class:

```
public class home
{
    public List<row> contents;
}
public class row
{
    public List<content> content;
}
public class content
{
    public int idContent;
    public string title;
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
home h = new home();
h = (home)CreateObject(xml, h);
```

Remember that the variable and class names must be exactly same as that of XML nodes.

**EXTRA:**

If you want to convert a class object into XML String, use this method:

```
string CreateXML(Object YourClassObject)
{
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();   //Represents an XML document, 
     // Initializes a new instance of the XmlDocument class.          
     XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(YourClassObject.GetType());
     // Creates a stream whose backing store is memory. 
     using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, YourClassObject);
         xmlStream.Position = 0;
         //Loads the XML document from the specified string.
         xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
         return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
     }
}
```